# why does a higher max-width in media queries overwrite a lower max-width?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

The width of my page is under 991px and still the 'max-width 1200px' is overwriting my 'max-width 991px' rule in css.

This is a screenshot of my devtools window  :

[image]

This can be solved by putting '!important' behind the 'margin-top...' css rule. But still I want to know why this is the case.

Comment: It looks like it is applied because it comes later on in the css file. The 991 px is applied around line 462 and the 1200px is applied after at line 506. Instead of `!important`, which you should steer clear of in almost all cases, you can just make your selector more specific. For example, if you had something like `P {}` you could make it more specific by adding classes/ids/child elements/etc.. `P.someClass > child #someID`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you have to change the order of your media queries...

in your case, the smaler the max-width, the lower it should be in you css

because `max-width: 1200px` is also true and comes later, so it gets overridden (look at the line count! :) )

Comment: Thank you ! I didn't know this !

Comment: @JimPeeters CASCADING style sheets. Locations and order can be very important.

Comment: I have pretty much found your answer just after I spent a lot of time in order to enforce obedience by programatically generating `css` with exact width brackets in `.cshtml` for my custom column classes. I would have never suspected that order can be the issue, thanks. At least now I have `LESS/SASS` on steroids and in `C#` as a side effect.